# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-modal

i have use bootstrap popup notification .to show the site notification.
Now it is not working. I can't figure out why

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "AlertBox", "BootstrapDialog.alert('تغییرات شما با موفقیت اعمال شد');", true);

System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "BootstrapDialog.alert('نظر شما با موفقیت در سامانه ثبت شد');", true);
```

Comment: You can try to add a label or literal on markup, and then you can change its text as "<script..... </script>

Comment: Try changing Page (or `this`) in `Page, typeof(Page)` to the ID of your UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add script manager control in your page